# Can we use scriptlets inside Javascript?

Tags: javascript, jsp, scriptlet

Here is my Code:

```
<%@page contentType="text/html"%>
<%@page pageEncoding="UTF-8"%>
<%@page import="java.sql.*"%>
<!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01 Transitional//EN"
   "http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/loose.dtd">
<html>
    <head>
        <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8">
        <title>Example of Java Server Page with JDBC</title>
    </head>
<script>
function myFunction() {
    var x='<% request.getParameter("ServerName"); %>';
    alert(x);
</script>
<body>
<form>
    ServerName:  <input type="text" name="ServerName"   required> <br><br>
<input type="submit" id="btnSubmit" name="btnSubmit" />
            </div>
            </form>
  </body>
</html>
```

Here in the above function onclick of a button i want to execute the scriptlets which is inside javascript?

Comment: What happened when you tried it?

Comment: You shoud avoid scriptlet in jsp. Use [EL](https://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/tutorial/doc/gjddd.html) or [JSTL](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/5/tutorial/doc/bnakc.html)

Comment: The alert box was empty @epascarello

Comment: Thanks for  your suggestion vinoth but i would like to give it a try.

Comment: use `var x='<%=request.getParameter("ServerName")%>';`

Comment: Its not working srinu

Answer (score 1):

you can also use this:

```
<%@page contentType="text/html"%>
<%@page pageEncoding="UTF-8"%>
<%@page import="java.sql.*"%>
<%
String ServerName = (String)request.getParameter("ServerName");
%>
<!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01 Transitional//EN"
   "http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/loose.dtd">
<html>
    <head>
        <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8">
        <title>Example of Java Server Page with JDBC</title>
    </head>
<script>
function myFunction() {
    var x='<%=ServerName%>';
    alert(x);
</script>
<body>

    ServerName:  <input type="text" name="ServerName"   required> <br><br>
<input type="submit" id="btnSubmit" name="btnSubmit" />
            </div>
            </form>
  </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 1):

You can, but if you want the result to be passed to the JavaScript you have to *output* something.

```
var x='<%= request.getParameter("ServerName"); %>';
         ^ output!
```

… and unless you take measures to escape that data, you render yourself vulnerable to XSS attacks.

(And, obviously, this won't work until the form is actually submitted)

Comment: @srikanthr — What more detail do you need? It's a basic concept and a one character fix which I highlighted for you in the answer.